# App runs in Release build, but receive FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION in Debug

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I am getting some unhandeled exceptions that I don't understand.
It is a Xamarin Android App. The app runs perfectly fine using the **Release** build, however, when run in **Debug** the UI hangs and I get this error:

> [mono]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[SpotifyWebAPI.Models.PrivateProfile].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
>   [mono]   at IntervalAndroid.MainActivity+c__async0.MoveNext () [0x0006d] in /Users/f/Projects/FourByFourInterval/IntervalAndroid/MainActivity.cs:390 
>   [mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   [mono-rt]   at SpotifyWebAPI.SpotifyWebAPIClass+c__async1A.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0 
>   [mono-rt] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

etc. The full error can be [viewed on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GZWqzC74)

EDIT 2: In Debug mode choosing to "Run without debugging" works perfectly fine. 
EDIT: Setting *Debug information* in *Project options* to **None** solves the issue, but **Symbols only** and **Full** persists.

I have read that not having the correct android.permission.*, but since it works in Release (and not the otherway around where android.permission.INTERNET might be an issue) I don't think so.

But honestly, I have no idea.
Thank you for helping out

- Fred

Comment: Are you using an API which needs some sort of key tied to your signing certificate?  If so, you probably need to use one tied to your debug certificate rather than your release certificate.

Comment: Hi, @ChrisStratton, thanks for helping out. The API I am using is a simple WebApi using Json. The app runs fine in Debug mode in the Emulator, so you might be on to something. However, I have made sure the app is Debuggable, so I don't understand why it's not working on the device. Any ideas?